# Django - Custom form widgets which are not inputs

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to create a custom form widget which consists of a hidden form field and an image link.  I've had a look through the source and the documentation and it seems like this might be hard to accomplish. The image would launch a modal popup which would return a value to the hidden field.

Does anyone know if a 'complex' widget like this would be possible? The admin date picker is similar to what I want to achieve but I can't seem to locate the source for that.

Oh, and it'll need to work outside of the admin panel.

Comment: You're looking for [`AdminDateWidget`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L47)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone wants to know how to do this, take a look at the admin files. I achieved what I wanted to do like so:

```
class MediaUploadWidget(HiddenInput):
    def __init__(self, attrs={}):
        super(MediaUploadWidget, self).__init__(attrs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        output = []
        if value is None:
            value = _('Upload Image')
        output.append('<a href="#" class="upload_image">%s</a>' % value)
        output.append(super(MediaUploadWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs))
        return mark_safe(u''.join(output))
```